# Makefile prepend and append all elements in array

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a Makefile, I have a list of all the files (without `src/` or `.cpp`), and I want to convert those to `build/*.o`. Here's what I've tried already:

```
FILES=icxxabi list memory string
OBJECTS=$(echo ("${build/$$FILES[@].o}")[@])
```

So for the input `a dir/b c`, it should output:

```
build/a.o build/dir/b.o build/c.o
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With GNU Make, you could try

```
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %, build/%.o, $(FILES))
```

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at the make [file name functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions):

```
OBJECTS = $(addprefix build/,$(addsuffix .o,$(FILES)))
```

Comment: NOTE: this is more readable than `patsubst`, but only in its simplest form. Use `$(patsubst %, <prefix>%<suffix>)` for more complex scenarios